# View filter - Show content that has 1 field matching another field in current node

Tags: views

I have a content type called **Specifications** which has 4 fields

- *Engine Specifications*
- *Features Specifications*
- *Variation* (exposable filter)
- *Model*

I also have another content type called **Cars** which has 1 field called *Model* too.

I am created a  SpecificationsView which displays the content-type **Specifications** as a block in **Cars**.

Is it possible to show in each **Car** the **Specifications**  whose *model* matches the current ''**Car**'' node's *model*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using entity reference module and some php code in views.
All you need to do is use entity reference module make a view that list model taxonomy terms as entity reference display.

Then you need to add a er(entity reference) field in both content type and input in that view you just made then make another view that list specification fields add a relationship to add entity reference model field add a contextual filter taxonomy term id in provide a default value choose PHP code and paste this code :

```
$nid = arg(1);
$node = node_load($nid);
$term  = $node->field_model['und']['0']['entity']->tid;
return $term;
```

Or refine this code by yourself.

Comment: Use [LANGUAGE_NONE] instead of ['und'].